# querySelector div < child // .class[dataField] < .class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not really well educated in jQuery, but I need a selector for the following:

```
<div class="shepherd-step shepherd-theme-dark shepherd-has-title shepherd-element shepherd-element-attached-top shepherd-element-attached-center shepherd-target-attached-bottom shepherd-target-attached-center shepherd-open shepherd-enabled" 
        data-id="DataType">
    <div class="shepherd-content">
        <header><h3 class="shepherd-title">Data Type</h3></header>
        <div class="shepherd-text"><p>Choose Your Desired Data Type!</p></div>
        <footer><ul class="shepherd-buttons">
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-secondary">Close</a></li>
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-example-primary">Next</a></li></ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fields of Interests: `shepherd-step` / `data-id="DataType"` / `shepherd-button-example-primary`

but I have a knowledge gap to handle it with JQuery

I tried something like this: `.shepherd-step[data-id="DataType"] > .shepherd-button-example-primary`

to address `[data-id="DataType"]` working fine, but I want the button and not the whole div

Comment: `>` means *direct descendant` - remove that (replace with a space ` ` for any-descendant) and you'll be good to go

Comment: More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators

Comment: xD omg, thanks, i tried many thing but not a space

Comment: now i had a other problem. I have multiple data-ids to address/select the right button. The HTML code is all the same but its not working for the other values ;/ Only the first selector is working. (all selectors are working fine alone but not together)

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question, then you can include your code / enough code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Ok, a new question or shall i edit my exiting one?

Comment: Once a question has been answered (even before accepted), do not substantially change your question other than to add clarification.  So, in this case, a new question.   You can, ofc, ask minor follow on questions, but in this case you'll need to provide a lot more details (examples of the other values, the updated selector etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `>` from your selector so it becomes:

```
.shepherd-step[data-id="DataType"] .shepherd-button-example-primary
```

The use of the [Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>` means that the button must be a direct child of the `shepherd-step` div. This is the reason it did not work. By removing the child combinator, you're using the [Descendent Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), and the button is a descendent of the div; therefore, the button will be found.

Comment: xD omg, thanks, i tried many thing but not a space. And thanks for explanation

Comment: now i had a other problem. I have multiple data-ids to address/select the right button. The HTML code is all the same but its not working for the other values ;/ Only the first selector is working. (all selectors are working fine alone but not together)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to do you just have to use `$("CSS selector")` you can use all the CSS selectors in jquery to select a certain element from DOM.

**Here is this example I changed the text of both the buttons using jQuery **

```js
$(".shepherd-button-secondary").text("Changed From Script Close Button");
$(".shepherd-button-example-primary").text("Changed From Script Next Button");
```

```html
<div>
<div class="shepherd-content">
        <header><h3 class="shepherd-title">Data Type</h3></header>
        <div class="shepherd-text"><p>Choose Your Desired Data Type!</p></div>
        <footer><ul class="shepherd-buttons">
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-secondary">Close</a></li>
            <li><a class="shepherd-button shepherd-button-example-primary">Next</a></li></ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Importing the Jquery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have multiple .shepherd-button-example-primary and want toidentify them by data-id. But I got a answer, Thanks